# Installed Ubuntu Linux 11.04, but no eye candy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 but the interface does not look anything like the screenshots shown on the Ubuntu web site at:  http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/whats-new

What can I do to get all the original settings of 11.04?  At one point I had compwiz installed, but I've un-installed it now using the Synaptic Packet Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Does your graphics card support Unity? It is the name for new desktop interface and eye candy you are talking about. If not Ubuntu starts in Classic mode as in earlier versions of Ubuntu. You can check it with a Live CD. Also if you have NVIDIA graphics card you will have to install proprietary drivers to see that. Meanwhile install compiz as Unity is based on Compiz.